# Detecting if device audio equalizer is enabled

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

Some Android devices have audio equalizer settings - for example, on Huawei (on the P9 Lite at least) you can enable the "Headset SWS Effect". I know Sony and Xaomi devices also have similar settings.

Is there any way to detect, programmatically if such effects are enabled?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by this.

```
Equalizer equalizer = new Equalizer(0, player.getAudioSessionId());
   boolean isEnable=equalizer.getEnabled();

  if(isEnable){
    //put your code
   }
```

Happy coding!!

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I get: `AudioFlinger could not create effect, status: -22
AudioEffect initCheck failed -3
Error code -3 when initializing AudioEffect.`
I am not trying to use sessionId 0.

Comment: Seems like this is related: https://community.spotify.com/t5/Android/No-equalizer-on-my-new-huawei-p9/m-p/1427831/highlight/true#M64502
So I don't think the Huawei `Headset SWS Effect` is something that can be detected by using the Equalizer class.